# SQL Server - UNION ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I'm new to SQL development and I need to do UNION on two select statements. Below is a sample query. The Join tables & conditions, where criteria, columns names and everything is the same in both the select statements except the the primary tables after the FROM clause. I just wanted to know if there is a way to have a single static select query, instead of repeating the same query twice for the UNION (without going for a dynamic query).

```
SELECT Sum(ABC.Intakes) As TotalIntakes, Sum(ABC.ClientTarget) as TotalClientTarget
FROM(

    SELECT Sum(tt.IntakesReceived) As Intakes, Sum(tt.ClientTarget) As ClientTarget, 
        tt.ProgramId 
    FROM 
        (SELECT Count(DISTINCT ClientID) As IntakesReceived,  
           DATEDIFF(MONTH, L.AwardStartDate, L.AwardEndDate)*L.MonthlyClientTarget As ClientTarget, 
           L.AwardId, L.ProgramId
        FROM IntakeCoverageLegacy As L
          LEFT JOIN UserRoleEntity URE ON URE.EntityId  = L.AwardId
          LEFT JOIN CDPUserRole UR ON URE.UserRoleId = UR.Id AND UR.CDPUserId = @UserId     
        WHERE (@Program IS NULL OR L.ProgramId IN (SELECT ProgramID FROM @ProgramIDList)
          AND (ufn_IsInternalUser(@UserId) = 1
               OR (ufn_IsInternalUser(@UserId) = 0 AND UR.CDPUserId = @UserId ))    
        GROUP BY L.AwardId, L.ProgramId) As tt  
    GROUP BY tt.ProgramId, tt.ProgramName             

 UNION ALL

    SELECT Sum(tt.IntakesReceived) As Intakes, Sum(tt.ClientTarget) As ClientTarget, 
        tt.ProgramId 
    FROM 
       (SELECT Count(DISTINCT C.ClientID) As IntakesReceived,  
         DATEDIFF(MONTH, C.AwardStartDate, C.AwardEndDate)*L.MonthlyClientTarget As ClientTarget, 
         C.AwardId, C.ProgramId
       FROM IntakeCoverageCDP As C
          LEFT JOIN UserRoleEntity URE ON URE.EntityId  = L.AwardId
          LEFT JOIN CDPUserRole UR ON URE.UserRoleId = UR.Id AND UR.CDPUserId = @UserId     
       WHERE (@Program IS NULL OR C.ProgramId IN (SELECT ProgramID FROM @ProgramIDList)
           AND (ufn_IsInternalUser(@UserId) = 1
                OR (ufn_IsInternalUser(@UserId) = 0 AND UR.CDPUserId = @UserId ))   
       GROUP BY C.AwardId, C.ProgramId) As tt   
   GROUP BY tt.ProgramId, tt.ProgramName

) As ABC
GROUP BY ABC.ProgramId
```

OK... What I posted earlier was a sample query and I've updated the sample to my actual query to make it more clear. It's just the primary tables that are different. My requirement is that - after doing UNION ALL, I need to sum the aggregate columns in the final result, grouping by ProgramId.

Comment: There is no different in both queries, so why you use `union`?

Comment: @RubahMalam because the primary table is different

Comment: Ahh, sorry i didnt see it..

Comment: You could use `UNION` first: `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT .. FROM client UNION SELECT FROM LegacyClient) AS X LEFT JOIN ...`

Comment: @Lamak - I doubt that Test_User is familiar with derived tables. Are you going to create an answer? That will be the best solution.

Comment: It's probably faster as is. I was going to post Lamak's reply as an answer though.

Comment: @overslacked Ok, I posted my comment as an answer now

Comment: Both Lamak and shawnt00 gave the right answers and I was able to adapt the solutions given according to my requirement. But I could only mark one answer as correct and had to go with the one that was answered first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would probably first use `UNION` for the `Client` and `LegacyClient` tables as a derived table and then perform the `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT  C.AwardId, 
        C.ProgramName, 
        COUNT(ClientId) AS Intakes 
FROM (  SELECT  AwardId,
                ProgramName,
                Id
        FROM Client 
        WHERE Id = @ClientId
        UNION 
        SELECT  AwardId,
                ProgramName,
                Id
        FROM LegacyClient
        WHERE Id = @ClientId) C
LEFT JOIN UserRoleEntity URE 
    ON C.AwardId = URE.EntityId 
LEFT JOIN UserRole UR 
    ON URE.UserRoleId = UR.Id AND UR.CDPUserId = @UserId
WHERE (testFunction(@UserId) = 0
  OR (testFunction(@UserId) <> 0 AND UR.CDPUserId = @UserId))
GROUP BY C.AwardId, 
         C.ProgramName;
```

Comment: The difference here is the counted column - in the first case each group is counted separately. If @Test_User needs that information he'll have to add that in. Although, whether the distinction was important, is unknown....

Comment: @overslacked you are right, this isn't exactly equivalent to the first query, so it would be nice to understand the underlying problem op is facing

Comment: @overslacked Lamak's and OP's queries are equivalent. (assuming that `CleintId` is from either `UR` or `URE` table - otherwise Lamak's will throw error)

Comment: @ypercube - clever! Depending on what the OP's looking for, that'd be an easy solution.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not read the group by correctly. They may not be (equivalent)

Comment: You can't count on ClientId if you don't return it from the inner query. It won't quite work as you've got it.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT C.AwardId, C.ProgramName, Count(ClientId) as Intakes 
FROM
    (
    SELECT Id, AwardId, ProgramName, ClientId FROM Client UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, AwardId, ProgramName, ClientId FROM LegacyClient
    ) C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN UserRoleEntity URE ON C.AwardId = URE.EntityId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN UserRole UR ON URE.UserRoleId = UR.Id AND UR.CDPUserId = @UserId
WHERE
    C.Id = @ClientId
    AND (testFunction(@UserId) = 0 OR UR.CDPUserId = @UserId)
GROUP BY C.AwardId, C.ProgramName
```

Using `testFunction()` twice isn't really necessary (unless `null` is one of the outputs.) [image: Boolean logic]

You might also prefer to filter on `ClientId` outside of the union. I'm guess your purpose in rewriting it to avoid the duplicated logic. You might still want to see which one is better handled by the optimizer.

Also, I used a `UNION ALL`. I'm thinking you imagine only one result from one of the two tables. As you originally wrote it that count column is going to factor into the union.

Counting on `ClientId` seems odd. So does having a parameter named `@ClientId` that doesn't seem to match up with the `ClientId` column.

Comment: `OR UR.Id is not null` may be equivalent to `OR UR.CDPUserId = @UserId`. I might go with the first version if it's doing what I think it's doing.